# How can consistent initial processing times be obtained on builds uploaded to the App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ipa

When I am uploading new builds to the App Store, the processing times for new builds do not seem to be consistent. What I mean is that a build can go through processing quickly as in a matter of minutes and sometimes they seem to get stuck for hours or more. Needless to say, this interferes with my ability to readily use new builds for testing or for submitting them for review.

My question is, is there anything that can be done with regard to the packaging of my IPA or my build settings to obtain more consistent processing times on the App Store?

Please note that I am asking about the initial processing of an uploaded binary and not the time it takes for Apple to review an app.

I’m primarily uploading apps that use both Swift and Objective-C so the Swift runtime libraries are being included in my App Store package. I’m either submitting builds using Xcode 7.0.1 or a custom build script based on `xcodebuild`. Both methods have successfully uploaded builds but as I stated, the processing times can be wildly irregular and prompts me to reconsider how I am submitting my IPAs.

I want to note that this irregularity can occur at seemingly any time of the day so I’m not sure if that could be a factor.

From casual observation, it seems that newer builds will take priority over older builds. So if you have one build that has not completed processing, the newer build can finish processing before the older one. If a series of builds has been uploaded, the intermediate builds can be stalled for seemingly extended periods of time. This seems like a sensible approach in that more recent builds would have a higher priority in processing. I’m not entirely sure this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the experiences of other people having this problem and based on my own observations, I’ve concluded that it is possible for a build to get stuck in the `Processing` state, sometimes indefinitely. Since Apple does not provide additional information related to this condition, the solution to get more consistent processing times is to submit a new build if a build gets stuck at `Processing`. Whether or not this is a sure-fire method of affecting the actual processing time is yet to be proven by hard evidence.

Answer (score 0):

This question is open-ended.
App store review times vary wildly and even current time is not a reliable indicator of time if you submit now, but as a guide.

[Useful utility here](http://appreviewtimes.com)

Comment: I'm not asking about review times but rather the initial processing time on uploaded binaries.

Comment: There is none. IT depends on the load of Apple's servers and your binary size and library usage etc. It can be frustratingly long at times